# How to insert List<string> into SQL Server table as object?

Tags: c#, list, sql-server-2005

I make & use a datatable with a column through

```
test_dt.Columns.Add("list_paragraphs", typeof(List<string>));
```

In this way, I just need 1 row to save `List<string>` object which has many string items.

Is there a way to do this for Microsoft SQL Server 2005?

If available, the size of column is limited like 4000 (`varchar`)? Or enough like datatable?

I've searched for hours but there are only some threads talking about inserting a list with a loop row by row.

Comment: do you want to have in one SQL column to have the whole list content?

Comment: @styx, yes, in only 1 column, row. It's available in DataTable conveniently.

Comment: You can encode it as CSV and then decode it back after reading it from the database.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat, Thanks for your advice. I know some way like saving as xml but just doubt if there's direct, convenient way like datatable..

Comment: You could also use a blob but are you sure you want to do that ? It's against the first normal form.

Comment: you can also create a reference table and save the list name or indicator in the main table and on the reference table save the actual values

Comment: @Merlin, Thanks for your advice. If there's no convenient way, I can but I have to do with a complicated way.

Comment: @styx, Many thanks for your idea but seems more complicated....

Comment: @styx idea is actually more complicated but its the recommended way to go. You are using a relational database, in which you do no store aggregate of data in a simple row, that's bad practice. I recommend you read the first three normal forms and go for an association table.

Comment: @KayLee not that complicated :)

Comment: @styx, I deeply appreciate your kindness. Though I use relational DB, the aggregated paragraphs is only for 1 product as I'm working on insert paper of medicines. A obvious fact I've learned from SQL experts is there's no convenient way. Thank you ! :)

Comment: @Merlin, I deeply appreciate your kindness. Though I use relational DB, the aggregated paragraphs is only for 1 product as I'm working on insert paper of medicines. A obvious fact I've learned from SQL experts is there's no convenient way. Thank you ! :)

Comment: @Crowcoder, I'm using it in a DataTable. And .NET Framework version is 4.7

Comment: @KayLee yes but that is not a fully supported type for a DataColumn, which is part of makes up a DataTable. You lose functionality, though I guess if it works for you then you don't need that functionality.

Comment: @Crowcoder, thanks for your information. I've made a decision to go with xml in regard of my situation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yuo have several choices to **store** your data, but more important is the question: **What are you going to do with this?**

You might read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43494824/5089204) to find some general hints, in which cases storing *many values as one* might be a good idea - and when you should avoid this.

You can

- Use some delimiter and store all values as CSV

  - tight in storage
  - awful to read from
- Use some common format like XML or JSON (not supported in v2005)

  - rather tight in storage
  - better to read, but still clumsy
- Use a related side table, where you store your values together with a foreign-key-constraint *one-by-one*

  - A small overhead while storing
  - But - almost for certain! - the best way to go in your case.

> A obvious fact I've learned from SQL experts is there's no convenient way.

No, the convenient way is the related table. Any other approach is something you should have a really good reason to do this.

Comment: Many thanks for your support ! I've made a decision to go with xml. I also showed a thank in the useful link there. :)