# SQL Server 2016 column of User Defined Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a type like this

```
CREATE TYPE mytabletype AS TABLE 
(
     a int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     b int NOT NULL,
     c int NOT NULL                                
)
```

I want to create either a tabletype or a table like this

```
create type mytabletype2 as table
(
     a int not null primary key,
     b mytabletype
)
```

But SQL Server 2016 does not like the line `b mytabletype` - any workaround or tricks to overcome that?

Comment: SQL Server does not support nested table types. You could instead use XML or JSON.

Comment: Look at this: [JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), you can store any type of object in JSON format.

Comment: In a RDBMS this should be a related side table. XML or JSON might be a workaround, but will be a bad choice, if you want to use data **within** this "type" regularly... You might read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43494824/5089204)