# Need table structure for storing html tags and store and return its value

Tags: sql

I have a user form where admin enter additional html fields what ever he need he can add. such as textbox, drop down etc.how to store html tag in database its options eg: drop down with its list. storing user selected value for drop down. if we use textbox its have only scalar value to store not like drop down and radio button.how to manage this

Comment: This almost sounds like "how do I write an application or CRM". What it is though, is a very broad question with no details and considered very much off topic for [so].

Comment: Please be more specific in your questioning.

Answer (score 1):

In the table, keep your column type as XML and store the information there in the form of xml.

Comment: can i do it as json?

Comment: yes you can. This link can help you in doing the same      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494824/when-can-i-save-json-or-xml-data-in-an-sql-table